# How can I automatically set the width of an image retrieved from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

For my React Native app, I must import an image of an unknown width from an API. I already set the height of the image retrieved (30px). However, the image can be of any width.

Is there a way to set the width automatically based on the height I set? Is there a way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<Image style={styles.logo} resizeMode="contain" source={{url: `${Config.S3_COMPARATORS}/${this.props.account.institutionId}`}} />
```

The styles.logo only contains: `height: 30;`

I don't know the width or the aspect ratio. I only know the image is 100px of height and that the width is between 0 and 300px.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should maintain the aspect ratio:

```css
height: 100px;
width: auto;
```

Comment: Okay, I think I have an idea of what you are wanting, do you have a maximum width you want the images to be?

Comment: Yep, somewhere between 0 and 90px. I don't want to leave any blank space because there will be some text.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

In your componentDidMount() paste below method

```
let c = await this._getAspectRatio(IMAGE_URL)
            if(c!=null){
              c.h
              c.w
}
```

This is a helper function

```
async  _getAspectRatio(url){
    var aspectRatio = 0
    var c = 0;
    var h = 0 , w = 0;
        try{
        await Image.getSize(url, (width, height) => {
            console.log('>>url',url)
            console.log('width ',width,'==height ',height)
            console.log('ratio ',width/height)
            h = height
            w= width
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
    return {c , h, w};
}
```

Using the above methods you can have the dynamic height width of the image, the hold this dynamic height width using setState

Then apply it to the image

```
height:this.props.aspect[this.props.index].height*.06,width:this.props.aspect[this.props.index].width * .06,
```

Here .6 is just a multiplier you can switch between values to fit your image needs,